# When i use leftJoinAndSelect in Typeorm, There is an error not to use the table more than once

Tags: express, typeorm

win10, latest express, latest typeorm

```
@EntityRepository(Post)
export class PostRepository extends AbstractRepository<Post> {
  findPostById(postId: number) {
    return this.createQueryBuilder('post')
      .leftJoinAndSelect('post.user', 'user')
      .leftJoinAndSelect('post.postComments', 'postComment')
      .leftJoinAndSelect('postComment.user', 'user')
      .leftJoinAndSelect('post.likes', 'like')
      .leftJoinAndSelect('post.dislikes', 'dislike')
      .where('post.id = :postId', { postId })
      .getOne();
  }
}
```

If i use a above, i will get the following error

> The table name "user" is specified at least once.

```
.leftJoinAndSelect('post.user', 'user')
.leftJoinAndSelect('postComment.user', 'user')
```

How can I resolve this situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting an error because you are using the alias `user` for more than one join - `post.user` and `postComment.user`.

Try something like `.leftJoinAndSelect('postComment.user', 'postCommentUser')`.

Now if for example you want to select the user id of the user who made the post, you can specify that by `user.id`. If you wanted to select the id of the user who commented on the post, you can specify that by `postCommentUser.id`